# How to display the logs of the appspec file on jenkins console log?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a containerized(Docker) Django-python application deployed on AWS server to which I have configured cloudwatch. As we know the project kick-off starts from the appspec file. The appspec contains of the docker build, docker run commands

The appspec file logs can be monitored from the codedeploy agent by ssh in /opt/code-deploy/.. and also cloudwatch.

I need:

1) To display that deployment ID specific logs in jenkins console log.

2) If the deployment doesn't show up any error the build should **pass**.

3) If the deployment shows any error in the ssh logs while creating the image through the dockerfile the build should **fail**

Pasting my appspec file:

```
version: 0.0

os: linux

files:
  - source: .
    destination: /tmp

hooks:

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: install/aws/instance_clean_up
      timeout: 60
      runas: root

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: install/aws/docker_cleanup
      timeout: 60
      runas: root
    - location: install/aws/docker_build
      timeout: 600
      runas: root
```

Answer (score 0):

For #1, it's not so easy to pull that information on Jenkins, CodeDeploy is not streaming these logs through the API. You could sync your deployment agent log to CloudWatch and try to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html. Alternatively Beats+Logstash+Elasticsearch and firing queries to Elasticsearch, but that complicates your setup significantly, if you don't use ELK-stack in your infrastructure.

In case of #2 and #3, using CodeDeploy waiter should help - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/wait/deployment-successful.html

`aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id $DEPLOYMENT_ID`

You can get this `$DEPLOYMENT_ID` from triggering your deployment in CodeDeploy via `aws deploy create-deployment ...` as a response you get that `deploymentId` value.